# Page refreshing before submission

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that uses has a php tag in the head tag `<?php include_once("insert_emergency_dept.php"); ?>` my form has `action="insert_emergency_dept.php" action="post"...>` I have two pages like this each making use of their own respective included php file. Both of the php files have a `header(refresh=3; ...)`. What is weird to me is that one page continually refreshes before the form button is clicked and the other does not. Here is what my php file looks like, they are identical except for the data collected and where it goes.

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
include_once("php_includes/db_connect.php");

// Gather the posted data into local variables
$m = $_POST['MRN'];
$h = $_POST['hospital_name'];
$t = $_POST['trauma_team_activated'];
$i = $_POST['init_ed_diastolic_bp'];

// Get user IP Address
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));

// Form data error handling
if($m == "" || $h == "" || $t == "" || $i == ""){
    echo "The form submission is missing data.";   
} else {
    // End form data error handling
    $sql = "INSERT INTO nys_emergency_dept (mrn, hospital_name, trauma_team_activated, init_ed_diastolic_bp, ip_address, record_insert_dtime)
    VALUES('$m', '$h','$t','$i','$ip', now())";
}

if (mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql)) { 
  echo "Emergency Department Data has been inserted successfully.";
} else {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db_connect));
}

header("refresh:3; url=emergency_dept.php");
?>
```

I cannot understand why one page does not refresh until the form submission button is clicked and the other form continually refreshes every 3 seconds before the form is submitted.

Comment: Need more detail about your structure in order to help you. telegram @tje3d

Comment: if you include the page in the head it will be included and hearder will always be executed because isn't in a if statement .Also it refresh only in first page because it is included only once, I guess

Comment: @O.Rares I did not know that. I cleared the include_once() statement out of the page and now it works just find. I will also take it out of the other page.

Comment: Better include_once ,just add the refresh in the if statement

Comment: @O.Rares that is a better idea.